# facebook graph api retrieve if given user is my friend and also if i follow the user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am using facebook graph api, but I can't figure out how to check if given user id is my friend and i am following him/her.

i want to check if given user-id(ex: 1000152XXXXX) is my friend or not. and also if i am following the user. i am trying with this:

https://graph.facebook.com/1000152XXXXX?fields=name,email,is_friend,is_following&access_token=xxxx

help me anyone. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not check who’s following people, that info isn’t available via API.

Comment: i want to check if i follow him/her. facebook lite shows this info so its possible to get it

Comment: No, it is not possible. The API available to 3rd-party apps does not offer full access to just anything the official apps have access to.

Comment: i have access token from the facebook lite app. now can it possible?

Comment: Again, there is no field holding that information in the official APIs available to 3rd-party apps. And trying to sneak your way around that using access tokens you shouldn’t be using in the first place, and / or unofficial endpoints used by the native apps, is a good way to get your app shut down, or your account blocked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no field called `is_friend`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

In order to check if some user is a friend, make sure both users authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission and use `/me/friends` to get all friends of a user.